# Read in text file decimal number values and assign them to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't get this program to assign decimal numbers in a text file to variables.

```
with open("Inputpydata.txt", "r") as fo:
    line = fo.readline()
    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        avalue = line[4]
    line = fo.readline()
    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        bvalue = line[4]
    line = fo.readline()
    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        cvalue = line[4]
    line = fo.readline()

    a = float(avalue)
    b = float(bvalue)
    c = float(cvalue)

    sum = a + b + c

    print("a = ", a)
    print("b = ", b)
    print("c = ", c)
    print("sum = ", sum)
```

The input text file has 3 separate lines with `a = 1.0`,  `b = 2.0`, and `c = 3.0`. The `sum` value should be 6.0.

Modified working version:

```
with open("Inputpydata.txt", "r") as fo:
    line = fo.readline()
    avalue = line[4]
    line = fo.readline()
    bvalue = line[4]
    line = fo.readline()
    cvalue = line[4]

    a = float(avalue)
    b = float(bvalue)
    c = float(cvalue)

    d = a + b + c

    print("a =", a)
    print("b =", b)
    print("c =", c)
    print()
    print("d =", d)

with open("Outputpydata.txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.write("a = " + str(a) + "\n")
    fo.write("b = " + str(b) + "\n")
    fo.write("c = " + str(c) + "\n")
    fo.write("\n")
    fo.write("d = " + str(d))
```

Comment: What does the program do instead of giving you the result you want?

Comment: Also I submitted an edit to show the proper indentation, although as I can't get the program to do much I'm not sure if I got it right. Please fix if and when the edit is approved.

Comment: while looping giving a = 3.0  b = 3.0  c = 3.0 only taking last line value 3.0 for all variable values. Tomerikoo's answer helped me get it working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you never change `line` inside the `while` loops so basically already the first will get you to an infinite loop.

Second, you only take the 4th character of each line, so your code works for that specific example. If you would try `b = 2.5` it will fail. If the `=` sign would be padded with more spaces it will fail as well.

I guess that you were trying to go with something like:

```py
with open("Inputpydata.txt", "r") as fo:
    line = fo.readline().strip()
    print(line)
    avalue = line[4:]

    line = fo.readline().strip()
    print(line)
    bvalue = line[4:]

    line = fo.readline().strip()  
    print(line)
    cvalue = line[4:]

    a = float(avalue)
    b = float(bvalue)
    c = float(cvalue)

    sum = a + b + c

    print("a = ", a)
    print("b = ", b)
    print("c = ", c)
    print("sum = ", sum)
```

But you could make it a little bit more generic to support any amount of values and ignore whitespaces:

```py
with open("Inputpydata.txt", "r") as fo:
    variables = {}
    for line in fo:
        line_split = line.split("=")
        name = line_split[0].strip()
        value = float(line_split[1].strip())
        variables[name] = value

    print("a = ", variables['a'])
    print("b = ", variables['b'])
    print("c = ", variables['c'])
    print("sum = ", sum(variables.values()))
```

Of course this assumes all varaibles were in the file. If one was missing this will throw an error. You can also make the final printing more generic by doing:

```py
total = 0
for key, value in variables.items():
    total += value
    print(key, '=', value)
print("sum = ", total)
```

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo for your quick reply. I have to got your modified version of my program working, but without the ":" colons in the square brackets. I could not get your generic code to work. I also got a regular expression program from Dr Codie! on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1M4eCGKEJs&lc=z23xtzsqpkuvgxkndacdp43bogscpxv2wl4tbisj1tlw03c010c .

Comment: Hi @Billy, wihtout the `:` in the square brackets your program only takes the first digit. If you will try to run it with `a = 10.0` or `a = 4.5` it will not work. I changed my code and now it should be ok

Comment: @Billy and to your first comment: on such simple case I wouldn't bother with regular expressions. Although they are neat, in this case is simply not necessary

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, got another regular expression program that does the job. Here it is,

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, could not get your generic code to work.

Comment: @Billy there was a problem with indentation. Maybe that solved your problem. If not, try to be more specific. I also changed the list to be a dict for even more generality

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, only prints to screen a value with following error message, line 9, in <module>
    print("b = ", values[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, can you tell me how to do what I need to do when someone answers my question, as I could not find a way of responding on the website.

Comment: My above comment has a link where you can have all the information. You can vote on questions using the arrows to the side of each question and accepting the best answer by clicking the grey check mark under the arrows

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task easily if you opt to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Inputpydata.txt",header=None,names=['variables','values'], sep="=")
d = df['values'].sum()
print(d, type(d))
```

OUTPUT->

```
6.0 <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

where `Inputpydata.txt` file contains:

```
a = 1.0
b = 2.0
c = 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Utpal.